# Convert string date to show 2 year digits

Tags: vb.net

i have a string which has a value of "08-06-2008". I want the result to look like "08-06-08". Is there a way to do this? I've tried CDate but that only gives me 8/06/2008 which doesnt resolve the issue.

Comment: Your value - is it 08-06-2008 or 08-26-2008?

Comment: sorry corrected to 08-06-2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse it to `Date` and back to string:

```
Dim dt As Date = Date.ParseExact("08-06-2008", "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim result As String = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Since that is a normal format you could also omit the format string and use `Date.Parse` directly:

```
Dim dt As Date = Date.Parse("08-06-2008", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I have used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to avoid localization issues, normally your current culture is used in `Parse/ParseExact` and `ToString`.

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: thank you, I've found yours to be the best that worked in my situation. Everyone else, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, avoid CDate. It is a hangover from VB6, and is almost certainly less efficient than using the .net equivalent.

The following should give you the right answer:

```
string value = DateTime.ParseExact("08-06-2008", "dd-MM-yyyy").ToString("dd-MM-yy")
```

Note that your existing date format is ambiguous, so I've been unable to tell if you're meaning the 6th of August or the 8th of June - this is why I've used `ParseExact` over `Parse`. `ParseExact` is also slightly more efficient, as it tells the framework which format to use, rather than it having to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   Dim FormatString As String = ""
   Dim SampleDate As DateTime
    SampleDate = Now()
    FormatString  = Format(SampleDate,"dd-MM-yy")
```